# UTF-8 encoded HTML file: German Umlaute are not shown correctly (only question marks)

Tags: html, perl, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem showing German Umlaute "ÄÖÜ" in HTML pages when using UTF-8. Here is the example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";
print <<END;
    <HTML>
        <HEAD>
            <META CHARSET='UTF-8'>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
            <H1>The Country Österreich</H1>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
END
```

The result can be seen at:
http://5mls.com/test_bad.cgi
As you can see, the "Ö" is not shown.
Now the code that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";
print <<END;
    <HTML>
        <HEAD>
            <META CHARSET='UTF-8'>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
            <H1>The Country Österreich<!-- Э --></H1>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
END
```

The result can be seen at:
http://5mls.com/test_good.cgi
This time the "Ö" is shown correctly, because of the Russian character "Э" in the comment. Does anybody know, how the "Ö" could be shown without the comment with the Russian character?

I used UltraEdit V21 to create the source files and converted them to UTF-8. I used WS_FTP LE to upload the files on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't tell Perl how to encode the output.

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```